# Why does the exception thrown by some method not need to handle

Tags: java

For example, if I don't handle the `NumberFormatException` thrown by `Integer.parseInt()`, it could be complied; however, if I use the `Thread.sleep()` without a `try-catch`, there would be the `unhandled exception` error. Why?

Comment: This is related to checked and unchecked exceptions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the difference between checked exceptions (mandatory to be handled), and non-checked exceptions (optional to be handled) in Java.

Answer (score 1):

`NumberFormatException` extends [RuntimeException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/RuntimeException.html). Runtime exceptions are unchecked exceptions and do not need to be caught

Answer (score 0):

In short, if a method declares that it might throw an exception, compiler will force you to handle (with catch block) or redeclare it in case that exception is itself or subclass of Exception class.In opposite, if the declared exception is itself or subclass of RuntimeException class, compiler will stay silent and doesn't force you to do something. I also strongly recommend to look into differences between unchecked and checked exceptions as was said in other answers.